# Entity Framework Core + MariaDB - Navigation Property is null

Tags: mariadb, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have a many-to-many relationship defined using a table in MariaDB. I am trying to use Navigation Properties in Entity Framework Core for the related entities, but they're not hydrated.

`roles`

```
| role_id | role_name |
| 1       |  Role-A   |
| 2       |  Role-B   |
```

`groups`

```
| group_id |  group_name |
|  1       |   Group-A   |
|  2       |   Group-B   |
```

`role_to_group`

```
|  role_to_group_id   |   role_id  | group_id |
|          1          |    1       |   1      |
|          2          |    2       |   1      |
|          3          |    2       |   2      |
```

This is the class

```
[Table(name: "role_to_group")]
public class RoleToGroup
{
    [Column(name: "role_to_group_id")]
    public long RoleToGroupId { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "role_id")]
    [ForeignKey("RGToRoles")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "group_id")]
    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }

    [Include]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    [Include]
    public UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
}
```

The `[Include]` is a custom defined attribute for hydrating the navigation properties using the pattern similar to `DbContext.Set<T>().Include("property_name")` via an extension method that does reflection on `T` and finds all properties with the attribute `[Include]` defined on them.

However, I am unable to get this to work correctly. The navigation properties `Role` and `UserGroup` return null.

What do you suggest I am doing wrong? Also please let me know if you need any more details to be added to the question!!

Comment: I am not sure why you need the `[Include]` extension. Many-to-many relations are supported out-of-the in Entity Framework. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that EF Core doesn't automatically do  lazy loading. ( [Documentation about how to implement lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) ).

When installed these NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

and enabled lazy loading as e.g.:

```
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(@"User Id=root;Host=localhost;Database=Test;");

            optionsBuilder
                .UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        }

        public DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RoleToGroup> RoleToGroups { get; set; }
    }
```

I got it loaded:

```
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var roleGroup1 = context.RoleToGroups.First();
            Console.WriteLine(roleGroup1.Role.Name); //Role-A
            Console.WriteLine(roleGroup1.UserGroup.Name); //Group-A
        }
```

Lazy loading requires types to be public, and properties to be lazy-loaded must be virtual:

```
[Table(name: "role_to_group")]
public class RoleToGroup
{
    [Column(name: "role_to_group_id")]
    public int RoleToGroupId { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "role_id")]
    [ForeignKey("roles")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "group_id")]
    [ForeignKey("groups")]
    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; } //must be virtual
    public virtual UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }//must be virtual
}

[Table(name: "roles")]
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    [Column(name: "role_id")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "role_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table(name: "groups")]
public class UserGroup
{
    [Key]
    [Column(name: "group_id")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "group_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively to lazy loading, manual Eager or Explicit loading could be used from the same [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading).